# How to wait for firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).set() to finish before calling next function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using the following asynchronous function to write data to my firebase instance:

```
function writeUserData(uid, fn, ln, userEmail) {
  firebase.database().ref('users/' + uid).set({
    firstName: fn,
    lastName: ln, 
    email: userEmail
  });
};
```

Once writeUserData has finished, then I want to redirect the user to a different page:

```
window.location.href = "./mypage.html";
```

As far as I can understand, this can be done with [promises](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/keeping-our-promises-and-callbacks_76.html) but I could really use a good example to wrap my head around this.

Comment: That blog you linked to shows examples of using the then() method on a promise to continue doing work.  set() returns a promise, so you should be able to work with that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to firebase docs:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#receive_a_promise, the `set` method returns a promise. In that case, the simplest example for you would be:

```
function writeUserData(uid, fn, ln, userEmail) {
  firebase.database().ref('users/' + uid).set({
    firstName: fn,
    lastName: ln, 
    email: userEmail
  }).then(function onSuccess(res) {
    window.location.href = "./mypage.html";
  }).catch(function onError(err) {
    // do sth, e.g. console.error(err);
  });
};
```

The difference between your code and my example is the parts I've added:

```
.then(function onSuccess(res) {
  window.location.href = "./mypage.html";
}).catch(function onError(err) {
  // do sth
});
```

which in short means, "if request was successful, do `onSuccess`. If not - do `onError`.

You can get more info about how Promises work here: [Promise mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

---

To improve readability you could write it this way:

```
function writeUserData(uid, fn, ln, userEmail) {
  firebase.database().ref('users/' + uid).set({
    firstName: fn,
    lastName: ln, 
    email: userEmail
  })
  .then(onSuccess)
  .catch(onError);
};

function onSuccess(res) {
  window.location.href = "./mypage.html";
}

function onError(err) {
  // do sth
}
```